# How to send telegram message to a topic thread?

Tags: telegram, message

Recently Telegram added support for Topics in Groups in Bot API version 6.3 and this support added into python-telegram-bot version 13.15 (please find changelog https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/changelog.html)

Im sending messages like this:

```
{
  "@type": "sendMessage",
  "chat_id": "-1001580394181",
  "input_message_content": {
      "@type": "inputMessageText","text": {
          "@type": "formattedText","text": "test", "entities": [] 
       }
  }
}
```

and it works. They added message_thread_id parameter to define to which topic message should be sent. So i added the parameter:

```
{
  "@type": "sendMessage",
  "chat_id": "-1001580394181",
  "message_thread_id": "20451426304",
  "input_message_content": {
      "@type": "inputMessageText","text": {
          "@type": "formattedText","text": "test", "entities": [] 
       }
}
```

but message goes to main topic, there's no error or anything unless i'll provide incorrect message_thread_id, if so i'm getting message: `Code: 400, message: Invalid message thread ID specified`

What i'm doing wrong? The id's are correct i got them from catching the response from sending test message to topic channel.

Answer (score 8):

To send messages to Telegram Forum Topic you need to reply to a message saying

`"Topic" was created`

So basically every message you send in telegram topic is just a reply to this original message. You can check this if you view your Forum as Messages.

I, for example, have deleted that message so I:

- added my bot to the Forum
- created new topic
- opened link `https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/getUpdates`
- looked for `message_id` of topic created message

Here is how my message looked like:

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "result":
    [
        {
            "update_id": 1234567890,
            "message":
            {
                "message_id": 12345,
                "from":
                {
                    ...
                },
                "chat":
                {
                    "id": -12345678,
                    "title": "bruh",
                    "is_forum": true,
                    "type": "supergroup"
                },
                "date": 0987654321,
                "message_thread_id": 12345,
                "forum_topic_created":
                {
                    ...
                },
                "is_topic_message": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

So you can take either `message_id` or `message_thread_id`. In my case they were the same but I am not sure if there is a difference.

And now paste this `message_id` as a `reply_to_message_id` parameter in `bot.send_message()` method.

`bot.send_message(-12345678, 'Message for topic', reply_to_message_id=12345)`

Comment: Ok, but after a couple of minutes, it says "ok: "false", error_code: "400", description: "Bad Request: TOPIC_CLOSED". Now I cannot send more messages. The topic was not closed, just the "Topic" was created disappeared

Answer (score 0):

```
How in Google Script write?

function sendReminderToTelegram() {
  var telegramBotToken = "____";
  var telegramChatId = "-100CHAT_ID";
  
  // Проверка текущего времени
  var currentTime = new Date();
  var targetTime = new Date();
  targetTime.setHours(8); // Установка желаемого часа
  targetTime.setMinutes(0); // Установка желаемых минут

   
    // Создание сообщения
    var message = "Прошу проверить принтеры и заправить их.";
    
    // Отправка сообщения в Telegram
    var telegramUrl = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + telegramBotToken + "/sendMessage";
    var payload = {
      "chat_id": telegramChatId,
      "text": message,
    };
    
    var options = {
      "method" : "post",
      "payload" : payload
    };
    
    UrlFetchApp.fetch(telegramUrl, options);
  //}
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).