# Sending message via Telegram bot to a group on github updates

Tags: github, github-actions, telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-api

I need to send message whenever i push into my repository on github.

The following code is in gihub actions
**tg-notify.yml**  :

```
name: tg-notify
on: [push, pull_request]
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Update status
      uses: appleboy/telegram-action@master
      with:
        to: ${{ secrets.TELEGRAM_TO }}
        token: ${{ secrets.TELEGRAM_TOKEN }}
        message: |  #https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/contexts-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#github-context
         #Github_Updates:
         #Push_Commit ⚒:
          ${{ github.event_name }} commit in ${{ github.repository }} by "${{ github.actor }}". [${{github.sha}}@${{ github.ref }}]
```

I need to edit this code in order to send the message into telegram group.
NOTE: TELEGRAM_TO is the id of the person getting that message i have tried to replace it by group chat id but the problem is the message is sent to general topic.
is there a way to send that message in specific topic inside that group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out that the bot must have admin access to send message to that group.
Also the group chat id starts with a dash (-).

Answer (score 0):

To send messages to Telegram Forum Topic you need to reply to a message saying

```
 "Topic" was created
```

So basically every message you send in telegram topic is just a reply to this original message. You can check this if you view your Forum as Messages.

More: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75832985/11677524

appleboy/telegram-action doesn't support `reply_to_message_id`, but telegram api is very simple and can be used via single curl

```yaml
jobs:
  send_message:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Send Telegram Message
      run: |
        msg_text='Your message text here'
        curl -s -X POST 'https://api.telegram.org/bot${{ secrets.TOKEN }}/sendMessage' \
        -d "chat_id=${{ secrets.CHAT_ID }}&text=${msg_text}&reply_to_message_id=${{ secrets.MSG_ID }}"
```

GitHub Issue: https://github.com/appleboy/telegram-action/issues/57